# Difference between "matching" and "overlapping interests"

Tags: phrases, word-difference, phrase-choice

Is it possible to say that interests "overlap?" If it is, what is the difference between "overlapping interests" and "matching interests?"

Consider following examples:

> My interests are matching in particular the research of Mr. X
>
> My interests are overlapping in particular with the research of Mr. X

Which would be the better, more clear version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to say that interests overlap, but I wouldn't interpret them the same way.

---

> John and I have **matching** interests.

If you said this, I would interpret it to mean that you and John share most, if not all, of the same interests. Your interests match – they are the same. See this definition (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**match**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/match)
>   *Verb*
>
> **1** Correspond or cause to correspond in some essential respect; make or
>   be harmonious:
>   *[with object] "I thought we'd have primrose walls to match the bath"*
>   *[no object] "the jacket and trousers do not match"*

---

> John and I have **overlapping** interests.

I would interpret this to mean that you and John share *some* interests, but not all and probably not even a significant portion of interests. This is consistent with the dictionary definition:

> [**overlap**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overlap)
>   *Verb*
>
> **1** Extend over so as to cover partly:
>   *"the canopy overlaps the house roof at one end"*
>   *[no object] "the curtains overlap at the centre when closed"*
>
> > **1.1** *[no object]* Cover part of the same area of interest, responsiblity,
> >     etc.:
> >     *"the union's committments overlapped with those of NATO"*

---

Your examples sentences, I think, would be better if the order were reversed (and rephrased to use the simple present rather than continuous):

> The research of Mr. X matches my interests.
>
> The research of Mr. X overlaps with my interests.

You could also say "Mr. X's research..." but that would be down to writing style.

When *to match* is used in the present continuous (*is/are matching*), it sounds like the following definition is being used instead of your intended definition:

> **match**
>   *Verb*
>
> **1.1** *[with object]* Put (someone or something) together with someone or
>   something else appropriate or harmonious:
>   *"she was trying to match the draperies to the couch"*

Use of the continuous of *to overlap* just doesn't sound right in this context, although I can't provide further explanation as to why.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot. I guess I will go with "My interests are matching in particular the research of.."